# Why is mkntfs taking such a long time?

Tags: freebsd, ntfs

Under FreeBSD 12.0 the command `mkntfs -Q /dev/da3s1` (with the quick-format flag) still takes a *very* long time (not finished after some hours) for a 1 TB hard disk drive.

It gives the following warning:

```
The partition start sector was not specified for /dev/da3s1 and it could not be obtained automatically.  It has been set to 0.
The number of sectors per track was not specified for /dev/da3s1 and it could not be obtained automatically.  It has been set to 0.
The number of heads was not specified for /dev/da3s1 and it could not be obtained automatically.  It has been set to 0.
Cluster size has been automatically set to 4096 bytes.
To boot from a device, Windows needs the 'partition start sector', the 'sectors per track' and the 'number of heads' to be set.
Windows will not be able to boot from this device.
Creating NTFS volume structures.
```

How can I get a similar speed as in Windows for a quick format?

Comment: I doubt you can speed this up, because `ntfs-3g` works over FUSE. The only solution I see is to format using Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to a bug in the `ublio` library (a direct dependency of the `sysutils/fusefs-ntfs` port) - there is an open [bug](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=206978) report for it.

I recently faced the same problem, and the workaround I used was less than elegant - reinstall `sysutils/fusefs-ntfs`, but disable `UBLIO` support. You will then be able to run `mkntfs` to format your device. On 1TB, it'll be pretty quick - don't know how it compares to doing it natively under Windows, but it finishes, which is an improvement on hanging indefinitely!

If you then want to mount the NTFS device under FreeBSD, you'll want to reinstall `sysutils/fusefs-ntfs`, but with `UBLIO` enabled, or you'll get really poor IO performance on the drive. You could make a copy of the `mkntfs` binary built without `UBLIO` support somewhere on your path under a different name so you still have use of it if needed after reinstalling with `UBLIO`.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround (from the [the mentioned bug's last comment](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=206978#c19)) is to explicitly set the size of the partition at creation:

View Partitions/Drive:

```
gpart show
```

Destroy Partition/Drive:

```
gpart destroy -F da3
```

Create a GUID Partition Scheme:

```
gpart create -s GPT da3
```

Create a partition type (ntfs) and add the size (bytes, using “g” for GB):

```
gpart add -t ms-basic-data -s 4000g da3
```

*Would be great if someone can tell how to get the exact available size*

The drive needs a NTFS Filesystem and perform a fast format:

```
mkntfs --verbose --fast --label 4TB_HD /dev/da3p1
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Just faced this problem, but pkg-message of fusefs-ntfs-2017.3.23 suggest us to read /usr/local/share/doc/ntfs-3g/README.FreeBSD

> Current implementation does not properly work with partitions of size
> which is not a multiply of UBLIO_BLOCKSIZE (cannot read/write last
> cluster). For instance, you may not be able to create ntfs filesystem
> because of this

> The UBLIO layer is configured through environment variables

> NTFS_USE_UBLIO  - 1. Disabling it drastically decreases performance.

> UBLIO_BLOCKSIZE - 262144 (256KB). Larger improves reading/writing
> speed of large files, and smaller makes filesystem operations
> (creation, deletion, moving, find(1)) perform faster.

So possible solution is:

1. Disable UBLIO layer (and slow down NTFS). No     need to recompile anything. Just do

   ```
   setenv NTFS_USE_UBLIO 0
   ```

   (csh) or

   ```
   NTFS_USE_UBLIO=0
   ```

   (sh/bash) before running any ntfs tools in this terminal.
2. -or- Adjust UBLIO_BLOCKSIZE. Partition size must be a multiply of UBLIO_BLOCKSIZE. Set this variable same way as 1.
3. -or- Adjust partition size. Partition size must be a multiply of UBLIO_BLOCKSIZE, which is 262144 by default.
   Btw, I think that's impossible to hit this bug on medium, partitioned under modern Windows (Vista+), because Windows always creates partitions with size that is multiple of 1048576 bytes